# Python FTP retrieve breaks the FOR loop. I fixed it with try-catch block. Why does it work?

Tags: python, ftp, robotics

I am connecting to some robots in my workplace via FTP protocol to gather the backup data automatically. Script should iterate through all the folders and download all the files inside. However when I run the code below, the python script leaves `for folder in Folder_List:` loop after first iteration.
It's weird because when I tried to see what causes the bug by entering these commands in terminal, everything went through without an error.

After commenting parts of the code here I found out that the line `ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)` causes the loop to break.
In the robot os the parent folder is "/ROBOT" and other folders are inside like this: "/ROBOT/JOB" or "/ROBOT/DAT"

```
from ftplib import FTP
import os
import os.path

try:
    ftp = FTP('192.10.100.1')
    ftp.login('user', 'password')
    ftp.getwelcome()
    ftp.cwd('ROBOT/')

    save_dir_full = '/home/mint/Documents/robot_data'
    Folder_List = ftp.nlst()
    # Folder_List should be similar to this: 
    # Folder_List = ['JOB', 'DAT', 'CND', 'SYS', 'PRM', 'LST', 'CSV', 'LOG']

    for folder in Folder_List:
        if not(os.path.exists(save_dir_full +'/'+folder)):
            try:
                os.makedirs(save_dir_full +'/'+folder)
            except:
                #print('directory already exists')
                pass
        ftp.cwd(folder)
        filenames = ftp.nlst() # get filenames within the directory
        for filename in filenames:
            local_filename = os.path.join(save_dir_full +'/'+folder+'/'+ filename)
            file = open(local_filename, 'wb')

            # THERE \/
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)

            file.close()
            print(filename)
                
        ftp.cwd('..')

    ftp.quit()
                
except:
    print('Could not connect to ftp device')
```

After I added the try block, the loop did not break and the program finishes with success:

```
try:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
except:
    pass
```

Do you have any ideas why it worked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Do you have any ideas why it worked?*

First thing to do is to take closer look at what happend, to do this, replace:

```
try:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
except:
    pass
```

with

```
try:
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, file.write)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

and observe would your code will produce. As more general note usage of bare `except`, [is not recommended in python](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#except).

Comment: When I print out some of the content i get the output:

220 DX FTP server ( 1.07) ready.

saving in path:  backup2020W41/ASS6.1/10AR01

...downloading  JOB

550 not found

550 not found

...downloading  DAT

...downloading  CND

...downloading  SYS

...downloading  PRM

...downloading  LST

...downloading  CSV

...downloading  LOG

The pattern keeps repeating sometimes with more "500 not found" errors.

Comment: @Sayade: `550` is one of [FTP Permanent Negative Completion replies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_FTP_server_return_codes). It means file unavailable i.e. not found or you have not rights to access it.

Comment: That's true, I counted the downloaded files and they are missing one file per one "500 not found" error. Thank you for help